# Minor graphic glitch

Tags: bug, design

Every time I see this I cringe a little:

[image]

For comparison, the corresponding thingie in math.se always has the numbers centered in the circle.

Comment: If you breathe into a paper bag it prevents you from actually fainting. Worth a try. i saw this on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Bride_%281999_film%29

Comment: Also relevant: http://xkcd.com/1015/

Comment: Oh, the separation of C and E in offices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning

Comment: Oh snap, now I see it too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While we're on that note: [bad kerning](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/badfonts.jpg) (From [Keith Conrad's](http://mathoverflow.net/users/3272/kconrad) website.)